# Dynamic feature module error: cannot find symbol variable mipmap, menu, color etc

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, android-app-bundle

My Android Studio project has Android library, which contains mipmaps, drawables, menus, colors and layouts.

I have added this Android library to **app** module and its working perfectly, but after I added it to **dynamic feature module** it shows below errors when I build the project:

```
error: cannot find symbol variable color
error: cannot find symbol variable menu
error: cannot find symbol variable mipmap
```

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51253956/android-app-bundle-cannot-find-symbol-variable-for-resource/ ?

Comment: Please add more context to this (which packages are you declaring, where are the resources?)