# Android App bundle Cannot find symbol variable for resource

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I am trying to access the resource which is in `base.apk`, As documented I am placing all common source and resource in base app. But when I try to access the same  from dynamic-module its giving `error: cannot find symbol variable <resource>` 
What I have noticed is the R package in the dynamic module is different than the base app. But the IDE is not complaining anything.

Appreciate if anyone can help with this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to remove the R import statement generated in the dynamic module and use the same as in the App module.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to explicitly import the `R` file for the module you're requesting the resource from. For Kotlin I use import aliases like this:

`import foo.bar.base.R as Rbase`

So instead of `foo.bar.base.R.dimen.bar_foo_size` I can write `Rbase.dimen.bar_foo_size`. This also makes it fairly explicit to see where a resource is coming from compared to having to look into the imports.

Comment: Yeah! I have tried that and it is working fine. I was thinking the system would merge the R.java.
Also, I was trying to make an existing module to `dynamic-module` so would like to avoid refactoring the code to use explicit import for R statement